# Auditing Google App for Work E-Mail

Tags: email, google-apps, audit

Copied from this [document](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-audit/), can the source user for example `test@mydomain.com` and the destination user be `test@audit.mydomain.com`?

> Types of users in a monitored email scenario
>
> A monitored email scenario includes three types of users:
>
> Administrator — Any domain administrator can create, retrieve, update, and delete an email monitor using the Email Audit API's monitor resource. In addition, an administrator can use the API to retrieve user account information and download the mailbox. These operations can only be done within the domain over which the administrator exercises control.
>
> Source user — The source user is the user who receives or sends messages that are being audited by the monitoring destination user. Any domain administrator or account user can be a source user. The source user must be in the same domain as the administrator and destination user.
>
> Destination user — The destination user is the auditor who receives the audited email messages.

Answer (score 0):

The destination user (destUserName) goes off the primary username (regardless of audit.mydomain.com or mydomain.com). If audit.mydomain.com was added as a subdomain to mydomain.com and test@audit.mydomain.com was his primary email address it will work with the input:

```
name='destUserName' value='test'
```